# Slow scrolling because of MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

I was scrolling through the answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852399/minimum-value-of-fracb1ab-2) question of mine and the cursor hanged frequently. It even took time to load the content. Even while typing comments, my laptop hanged and the speed was slow because of too much MathJax present on the page.

How do I handle this?

Same happens here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Scrolling down on the posts which have heavy MathJax content is a very difficult task.

Comment: I am not sure how difficult it is to do this on mobile device, but have you tried changing Math Renderer in the MathJax menu? Judging by the name, "Preview-HTML" is probably lower quality but faster.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is on a mobile device as I find it hard to imagine even a low-end laptop/desktop computer struggling with this much.

The most likely solution (besides just living with it) is to try a different browser. If all browsers perform poorly, then your device may simply be under-powered and/or other applications/add-ons are causing it to perform poorly.

As a work-around, you could use some JavaScript blocking add-on, such as uBlock, to block the MathJax JavaScript. Obviously, this will mean the MathJax will not be rendered. These tools usually make it reasonably easy to enable/disable the JavaScript, so you can disable the MathJax JavaScript only when it is problematic.

Comment: My desktop struggles a bit on the tutorial page, though it's not exactly the best desktop to begin with...